# WPF Converter Property

Tags: wpf, binding, converters

I have a converter that in code I can set a property like:

```
tabAssumptions.SetBinding(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, new Binding("CurrentPhase.IsWholeScheme") { Converter = new BoolToVisibilityConverter { Inverse = true } });
```

How can I set the Inverse property of the converter when used in XAML?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My BoolToVisibilityConverter is below.  You can either use it as a resource:

```
 <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="FalseToHidden" 
     TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Hidden" />
```

or use it as a MarkupExtension inline in your XAML:

```
  Visibility="{Binding MyFlag, 
      Converter={vc:BoolToVisibilityConverter 
                 FalseValue=Collapsed, TrueValue=Visible}}"
```

C#

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Visibility>
{
    #region Constructors and Destructors

    public BoolToVisibilityConverter()
    {
        this.TrueValue = Visibility.Visible;
        this.FalseValue = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Use as the base class for BoolToXXX style converters
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>    
public abstract class BoolToValueConverter<T> : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    #region Constructors and Destructors

    protected BoolToValueConverter()
    {
        this.TrueValue = default(T);
        this.FalseValue = default(T);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public T FalseValue { get; set; }

    public T TrueValue { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ? this.TrueValue : this.FalseValue;
    }

    // Override if necessary
    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(this.TrueValue);
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    #endregion
}
```